# cmake target created with custom_target fails

Tags: cmake, objcopy

I am trying to add a custom target to my Cmake project, which will output .hex file out of .elf. Here is a piece of script I use:

```
....
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
....
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf)
set(COMD "${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.hex")
add_custom_target(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.hex DEPENDS ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf COMMAND ${COMD})
```

Building ends up like this:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/captain/test
[100%] Built target test.elf
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Oihex /home/captain/test/Release/test.elf /home/captain/test/Release/test.hex: not found
.... blah blah blah ...
```

Running directly:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Oihex /home/captain/test/Release/test.elf /home/captain/test/Release/test.hex
```

works just as expected. How might it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you wrap the command in `"`:

```
set(COMD "${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.hex")
```

Remove the surrounding `"` and it should work as expected:

```
set(COMD ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -Oihex ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
```